# How make work a search filter in react for node array

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, react-hooks

Hi guys i make a search filter in react for an array i get via my node server,  but i got this error: 
×
TypeError: props.filteredCharacters.map is not a function in components/CharacterList/index.js:6

Here the 2 files:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import SearchBox from '../SearchBox'
import CharacterList from '../CharacterList'



const SearchDisney = () => {

  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState('');
  const [btn, setBtn] = useState(false);
  const [apiResponse, setApiResponse] = useState([]);
  const [searchCharacter, setSearchCharacter] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {

    callAPI();

    if (inputs.length > 2) {
      setBtn(true)
    } else if (btn) {
      setBtn(false)
    }

  }, [inputs, btn])

  const callAPI = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:9000/disneyCharacter")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => setApiResponse(res))
  }

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    setSearchCharacter(e.target.value)
  }

  const filteredCharacters = () => {
      apiResponse.filter((character) => {
       return character.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchCharacter.toLowerCase())
    })
  }

  return (

    <div className="search-container">
      <h1>Personnage Infos</h1>
        <SearchBox handleInput={handleInput} />
        <CharacterList filteredCharacters={filteredCharacters} />
    </div>
  )
}


export default React.memo(SearchDisney)
```

And the CharacterList:

```
import React from 'react'
import Character from '../Character'

const CharacterList =  (props) => {

  const characters = props.filteredCharacters.map((character, id) => {
    return <Character key={id} name={character.name} username={character.username} yearCreation={character.yearCreation}/>
  })

  return (
    <div>
        { characters }
    </div>
  )
}

export default CharacterList
```

i can display the array in the first file but now i want to make search filter and got this error, any advice to get ride of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are 2 things you need to fix here:

on the `SearchDisney` component, you are not returning anything from the `filteredCharacters` function. Here is the fix:

```js
  const filteredCharacters = () => {
     //need to return this 
     return apiResponse.filter((character) => {
       return character.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchCharacter.toLowerCase())
    })
  }
```

Addtionally, in order for `CharacterList` to recieve the `filteredCharacters` prop as an array - you have to call the `filteredCharacters` function which returns this array, for example, like this:

```
 <div className="search-container">
      <h1>Personnage Infos</h1>
        <SearchBox handleInput={handleInput} />
        //call the function here:
        <CharacterList filteredCharacters={filteredCharacters()} />
    </div>
```